# Maintaining rsync log file

Tags: logging, rsync

I have a `cron` running `rsync` for backup purposes, and `rsync` logs the output to a file via `--log-file`. This script will keep on running for a quite long time and I am worried that the log file will keep growing. I can imagine that `rsync` doesn't have the mechanism to purge the beginning of the log file. What would you suggest?

Comment: You have to use a `logrotate`

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I didn't know about the command. From the man file, I can say that it seems quite useul. Make it an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You can find type of logrotate, looking for , logrotates are keeping your log files and after exceeding your log files , then compress it and copy .

Comment: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/understanding-logrotate-utility

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the append option? If so you might change this and use a logfile with a date and time in it. This way you get separate files for every run. Remove those files on a regular base.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was going to go this way. It just seems tedious to script to maintain a simple log file.

Comment: I know it is work to create a script like that. I use a script that removes a lot of logfiles from several applications/scripts that are older than a number of days. If it is only this then `logrotate` is a better solution.

Comment: Yes, it is only for a single log file. Appreciate the answer though!